# Page scroll down automatically on refresh in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, scroll

Internet explorer scrolls down the page automatically on page refresh and puts focus where I was before refresh. I have tried following things to override this behavior BUT nothing worked :

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}); // option 1

window.onload = function () {
  jQuery('body').css({'overflow': 'auto', 'position': 'static'});
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}; // options 2
```

I have "h1" tag at the top of the page and I tried to put focus on the that element too by this code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('pageHeader').focus();
        }); // Option 3
```

Above all code executes BUT after all this IE throws focus where I was before refresh. My problem is I am using screen reader to read the page content so I want the page to scroll to TOP on each page refresh. Everything works fine on Chrome. Please help me.

Comment: What is your problem statement? Do you want to scroll up to the top when the page refreshes?

Comment: @PraneshRavi Yes. I want my page to scroll up on refresh. Updated my question too.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all browsers...

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```